# Grafana dashboard doesn't display data in Rancher UI

Tags: kubernetes, grafana, prometheus, rancher, rke

I enabled monitoring for my project in Rancher UI, and it installed succesfully. But when I click *"Go to grafana"* at my workload (such as `nginx`), it moves to Grafana dashboard, but Grafana show nothing: `0 CPU, 0 memory, 0 networking` ,...

- Why doesn't it have data ?
- And how I can know consumed quota of my resource (workload, service, pod)?

Please see my screenshots:

[image]
[image]
Many thanks

Answer (score 1):

Prometheus is necessary component for using Grafana.

You can check this blogpost:

> [Kubernetes Monitoring with Prometheus, Grafana and Rancher](https://rancher.com/blog/2018/2018-10-18-monitoring-kubernetes/)
>
> [Prometheus](https://prometheus.io) is an open-source application for monitoring systems and generating alerts. ... Prometheus will scrape targets at designated intervals and store the information in a time-series database.
>
> [Grafana](https://grafana.com) is also open source and runs as a web application. ... Grafana makes it easy to create graphs and assemble those graphs into dashboards.

Check, if check if `Prometheus` is turned on and whether it is configured correctly:

> [Configuring Project Monitoring](https://rancher.com/docs/rancher/v2.x/en/project-admin/tools/monitoring/#configuring-project-monitoring)
>
> From the Global view, navigate to the project that you want to configure project monitoring.
>
> - Select Tools > Monitoring in the navigation bar.
> - Select Enable to show the Prometheus configuration options. Enter in your desired configuration options.
> - Click Save.

Also check these settings:

> [Prometheus Configuration](https://rancher.com/docs/rancher/v2.x/en/cluster-admin/tools/monitoring/prometheus/)
>
> - [Enable Persistent Storage](https://rancher.com/docs/rancher/v2.x/en/cluster-admin/tools/monitoring/prometheus/#persistent-storage) for Prometheus Whether or not to configure storage for Prometheus so that metrics can be retained even if the Prometheus pod fails.
> - [Enable Persistent Storage](https://rancher.com/docs/rancher/v2.x/en/cluster-admin/tools/monitoring/prometheus/#persistent-storage) for Grafana Whether or not to configure storage for Grafana so that the Grafana dashboards and configuration can be retained even if the Grafana pod fails.

Comment: Thank you. I forgot installing Prometheus catalog. So, I installed it, and I got below error:  Failed to install app myprometheus-p-lggjt. Error: release myprometheus-p-lggjt failed: podsecuritypolicies.extensions is forbidden: User "u-noxcbyk7pz" cannot create resource "podsecuritypolicies" in API group "extensions" at the cluster scope